Can't run MPI application on Cluster with DMTCP
I'm trying to run NPB (3.4.2) benchmarks on a local cluster. I'm using DMTCP 2.5.2 and MPICH 3.3a2, both manually installed. After installing DMTCP and MPICH, I configured SSH on all nodes so they could ssh each other without passwords (using ssh-copy-id). I also edited /etc/hosts so that it only contains the IPs of all cluster nodes, like this:
master: 192.168.1.100
node1: 192.168.1.101
node2: 192.168.1.102

After setting this, I installed DMTCP and MPICH:
sudo apt-get install build-essential gfortran python gdb -y
wget https://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.3a2/mpich-3.3a2.tar.gz
tar xf mpich-3.3a2.tar.gz
rm mpich-3.3a2.tar.gz 
cd mpich-3.3a2
sudo ./configure 
sudo make
sudo make install 
cd ..
PATH=/home/manager/mpich-3.3a2/:$PATH ; export PATH

wget https://github.com/raphaelprados/TCC-2023-2/raw/main/dmtcp-2.5.2.tar.gz
tar xf dmtcp-2.5.2.tar.gz
rm dmtcp-2.5.2.tar.gz
cd dmtcp-2.5.2
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
ssh node which dmtcp_launch
ssh-keygen -t dsa
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id*.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo make clean
sudo make
sudo make install
cd ..

After running dmtcp_launch --join-coordinator mpiexec -np 8 --hostfile hostfile.txt ./NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/bin./lu.C.x, I get the following output on the launch terminal:
[47000] NOTE at ssh.cpp:423 in prepareForExec; REASON='New ssh command'
     newCommand = /usr/local/bin/dmtcp_ssh --ssh-slave /usr/local/hin/dmtcp_nocheckpoint /usr/hin/ss
h -x node2 fusr¥localfbin/dmtcp_launch --coord-host 0.0.0.0 --coord-port 7779 --ckptdir /home/manage
r /usr/local/bin/dmtcp_sshd --ssh-slave "/usr/1ocal/hin/hydra_pmi_proxy" --control-port master:4666
3 --rmk user --launcher ssh --demux poll --pgid 0 --retries 10 --usize -2 --proxy-id 1
[46000] NOTE at ssh.cpp:423 in prepareForExec; REASON= 'New ssh command'
     newCommand = /usr/local/bin/dmtcp_ssh --ssh-slave /usr/local/bin/dmtcp_nocheckpoint /usr/bin/ss
h -x node1 /usr/local/bin/dmtcp_launch --coord-host 0.0.0.0 --coord-port 7779 --ckptdir /home/manage
r /usr/local/bin/dmtcp_sshd --ssh-slave "/usr/local/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy" --control-port master:4666
3 --rmk user --launcher ssh --demux poll --pgid 0 --retries 10 --usize -2 --proxy-id 0

And this is the output on the coordinator terminal.
[1328] NOTE at dmtcp_coordinator.cpp:658 in onData; REASON= 'Updating process Information after fork()'
      client->hostname() = master
      client->progname()= dmtcp_ssh_(forked)
      msg.from = 18af 1fad8d756-55000-660e9fdb
      client->identity() = 18af1fad8d756-54000-660e9fdb
[1328] NOTE at dmtep_coordinator.cpp:717 in onDisconnect; REASON='client disconnected
      client->identity) = 18af1fad8d756-55000-660e9fdb
      client->prognamel) = dmtcp_ssh_(forked)
[1328] NOTE at dmtcp_coordinator.cpp:667 .in onData; REASON='Updating process Information after ex
      progname = dmtcp_ssh
      msg.from = 18af1fad8d756-54000-660e9fdb
      client->identityQ) = 18af1fad8d756-54000-660e9fdb
[1328] NOTE at dmtcp_coordinator.cpp:717 in onDisconnect; REASON='client disconnected
      client->identity() = 18af1fad8d756-54000-660e9fdb
      client->progname() = dmtcp_ssh

If I run mpiexec -np 8 --hostfile hostfile.txt ./NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/bin./lu.C.x it'll work as planned, and the execution will run correctly on all nodes. What can I do to solve the DMTCP issue?
